# Can I use WP Multi-site on a sub-domain with a different theme but use all the original site's posts/pages?

Tags: theme-development, multisite

I've been reading a lot about multi-sites but am still not 100% sure on this.   My use case scenario is that I have an original WP site which relies heavily on a lot of data in a custom post type.

The site now needs to be replicated onto a subdomain for a client that is going to have a "whitelabel" rebranded version of the site.   They need all the same functionality of the main site and to access/search the main site data.  Its just that the look of the subdomain site is very different and the client wants a subdomain to make it stand out.

Is this possible or would I have to replicate the posts from the main site to the new subdomain site if I want to access them everywhere?

Comment: Have you considered keeping this site in the network as-is, but mapping a new domain name to it?  Gives the exact look/feel of a completely separate site.  If you are on WP version 4.5.x you don't even need to use a plugin to make this happen.

Comment: @CC can you clarify with a little more detail?

Comment: sure, but it's too long to stuff into a comment here...so I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a solution I configured, which leaves the site in the network, but establishes a domain map from any registered domain, to the network.  It makes the network site appear to be a completely independent site, with all the functionality (log-in, etc.) intact.

**Goal:**

Map client's registered domain, both `www.foosite.com` and `foosite.com` over to our multisite network `mymultisite.com` - and make it as easy as possible on the client (i.e. no mucking around with CNAME or A records, at their registrar).

**Procedure:**

Using Amazon Route 53 as the DNS system.

1. With Amazon AWS Route 53 handles the DNS, so we first create a hosted zone for the client's registered domain (`foosite.com`) with a www CNAME record pointing to `www.mymultisite.com`
2. Set up an S3 bucket in Amazon AWS for the (non-www) client's `foosite.com` and **statically** map that to `www.foosite.com`
3. Back in the Route 53 hosted zone, create an A record for the (non-www) `foosite.com` and specify it as an Alias, pointing it to the bucket created in step 2. This assures that both `www.foosite.com` and `foosite.com` will end up pointing to `www.mymultisite.com`
4. In the multisite network, go to the client's site in network admin and edit the site URL, changing it to `www.foosite.com`
5. In the hosting account that hosts `mymultisite.com` specify an add-on domain (or a parked domain) called `foosite.com` and point it to public_html (or wherever you have WP installed). This effectively creates a virtual host record in Apache config, for the incoming mapped site.

(**note:**  If the multisite is hosted at a static IP address and is the only site at that address, and the hosting company allows dynamic mapping of incoming domains to the site's document root...then you don't have to use add-on or parked domains.  Check with your hosting company if unsure).

6. In your `wp-config.php` for the multisite, you need to add a line:  `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );`

**Result:**

You've established a complete DNS solution for the mapped domain.  All you have to do is tell the client to update their registrar for their domain, specifying the Amazon nameservers that are recorded in your hosted zone at Route 53 as their DNS.  Your clients don't have to mess around with CNAME or A records at all - you are handling the mapping completely, at Route 53.  Furthermore, due to the **magic** of the AWS Alias record, your multisite doesn't even need to be on a static IP address (although I keep it on one, just to be safe).

If using another system as the nameserver (e.g. Enom, or GoDaddy), you'd set up an A record for their domain which points to the static IP address of `mymultisite.com`.  This is an ok answer but it carries the risk that if your static IP address ever changes, you'd have to tell your clients to go update the A record at their registrar.

I like the Route 53 solution a lot better.  I also established a "white label" set of DNS at AWS following the guidance in [this article](https://galliard.xyz/essay/2015/12/aws-vanity-nameservers.html).  Now it is extremely simple - just tell clients here are your new nameservers to set at your registrar, and everything on the WP side works flawlessly.  No need to maintain a static IP address in an **A** record.

Comment: Thanks @CC but I'm not 100% clear that the solution you have posted answers my question, ie to ensure two different templates are served in each site and that both can access the same posts ?   Your stated goal doesn't mention this.

Comment: ah.  So, you want the network site to simply re-theme the base site and have access to all the same exact content from the base site?  I did miss that, I thought you were looking to split out a network site to be "on its own".  How about staying with one site and switching themes automatically:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-conditional-themes/

Comment: As mentioned in my question ,using two domains is vital as its part of what the client needs so is what you are suggesting possible over two themes with this plugin?

Comment: Adam, it might be.  You should look into two things (1) the dynamic theme switching idea and (2) at the host, pointing a subdomain to the existing domain - either via the host management tool (e.g. Cpanel), and/or via .htaccess rewrite rules.  I think the last thing I'd want to do is attempt two distinct sites served from the same set of WP tables, or some sort of DB synchronization idea.